# MariaDB is not Using Hash Unique Key on InnoDB

Tags: sql, indexing, mariadb, innodb, unique-constraint

I create a table with a text column with unique key:

```
create table a(id int auto_increment key,a text unique);
```

And when I run `show create table a;`, it says that the unique key is using hash:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `a` (`a`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

What I am expecting is that when I `insert into a (a)values('a');` and then `select * from a where a='a';`, it should use that key for searching. However it does not seem to, the query is slow on large dataset, and `explain select * from a where a='a';` produces the following:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | a             | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1    | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Why MariaDB is not using that key for searching?

When I add another key manually `alter table a add key b(a) using hash;`, it works as expected, just a warning `Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MDEV-13445](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13445), the MariaDB optimizer doesn't yet support using HASH indexes on text types.

Also see [MDEV-31072](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31072).

Comment: Wow. Does that also mean that unique key on text can potentially be very slow, as it is harder to check for duplication?

Comment: The code paths taken for query searches are different from those used for just inserting. I suspect inserting speed to comparable to any other index.

Comment: The lack of implementation isn't necessary because its slow, its just a little more complicated as it needs to check the actual row in addition to the hashed version in the index.

Comment: And collations may come into play.